# Redirecting From One Page to Another After Sending Login Credentials

Tags: asp.net

While I'm logged into a web application 1, I would like to navigate to web application 2 without explicitly logging on manually.

In application 1 I have an OnClick that gathers up my current login credentials and attempts to POST them to applications 2:

```
        long timestamp = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    string userName = currentUser.Credentials.UserName;
    string accountName = currentUser.Account.Name;
    string ssoUrl = AppUtil.SalesViewSsoUrl;
    var ssoKey = new Guid(AppUtil.SalesViewHashKey);

    // Build request
    System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(ssoUrl);
    string postData = BuildPostString(userName, accountName, timestamp.ToString("x"), ssoKey);
    byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);

    //Request.Headers.Add("SSOParams", postData);
    //request.Method = "POST";
    //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    //request.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;/

    //Stream sOut = request.GetRequestStream();
    //sOut.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
    //sOut.Flush();
    //sOut.Close();
```

So, the problem here is that I remain on the same page. I can't figure out how to do that basic operation but stay on the newly logged-in application 2 page.

Is there any other way to send those parameters over without putting them in a query string? I want to avoid that.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming that you can't use Response.Redirect(); What do you mean between two applications? Did you create the user roles and passwords correctly(Using ASP.NET tools)?

Comment: With Forms authentication you should be looking into SingleSignOn: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you should use ASP.NET Web Config tool. You can also handcraft your code. This website has lots of tutorials on ASP.NET. It has some videos about the *Authentication and Authorization*, etc. in the Advanced ASP.NET section. [Manzoor the trainer](http://www.manzoorthetrainer.com/)